# mysql take value from field and use it to relation table

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT p.name, p.ages, t.fi FROM person p
LEFT JOIN(
 SELECT person_id, SUM(the_field) as fi FROM o_tables WHERE s_field >= p.ages
 GROUP BY person_id
) t ON t.person_id = p.id
```

how to use `p.ages` value to relation table `o_tables` ?
I used variables `@p := p.ages` but in the second record is not change

Comment: give us some sample and expected result please?

Comment: Post FULL information set, not a part of it. *how to use `p.ages` value to relation table `o_tables` ?* I do not see any another mentioning for the table `o_tables`... where is it taken from? *but in the second record is not change* You show `SELECT` query which can change nothing in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just join person in the subquery too?

```
SELECT p.name, p.ages, t.fi FROM person p
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT person_id, SUM(the_field) as fi FROM o_tables 
    JOIN person p on p.id=o_tables.person_id
    WHERE s_field >= p.ages
    GROUP BY person_id
) t ON t.person_id = p.id
```

But I don't see the need for a subquery?

```
SELECT p.name, p.ages, SUM(the_field) as fi
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN o_tables on p.id=o_tables.person_id and s_field >= p.ages
GROUP BY p.id
```